# Placeholder for order by MySql query NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm developing in nodejs and using mysql library for query the database. Is there is a way to have placeholder for ORDER BY and order direction (ASC/DESC) rather that concatenating them directly to the query.
So we will have something like:
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE department_id=? ORDER BY ? ?`
and to put the values like this:

```
connection.query(query, [12, 'last_name', 'DESC'], function (executionError, result) {
     if (executionError) {
         reject(executionError);
     } else {
         resolve(result);
     }
});
```

Comment: Isn't it what you are doing right now ? What's the `query` string ?

Comment: It's not working with this.

Comment: What's the `query` ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM useres WHERE department_id=12 ORDER BY last_name DESC

Comment: Of course the values (12, last_name, DESC) shall be dynamic and passed to the query function

Comment: I am asking for a way to pass last_name, DESC dynamically like department_id value, rather than directly concatenating them

Comment: Apparently you might use `??` instead of simple `?` for identifiers but i'm not sure

Comment: It's not working, I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers) you should try something like this:

```
const sort = connection.escapeId('last_name');
const direction = connection.escapeId('DESC');
const query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE department_id=? ORDER BY ${sort} ${direction}`;
connection.query(query, [12], function (executionError, result) {
     if (executionError) {
         reject(executionError);
     } else {
         resolve(result);
     }
});
```

Comment: The problem with that implementation (even if it's working), is that it requires the connection object, in my case, the connection object is not directly exposed to the API I'm using to run queries. The API only exposes a method that accepts the query string and array of values

Comment: Can you try to expose the `escapeId` function ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but I'll see

Comment: It's not working